# How to modify Registry of window OS from c or c++

Tags: c++, c, windows

I want to modify the registry of window OS using c. kindly guide me or give me some hints so that I can make it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Win32 APIs such as [RegOpenKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724897(VS.85).aspx) for doing this.